# display array object in php (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I want to save an array object, but when I send it to the controller and call dd() it shows me like object not an array.
any assist would be really appreciated.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
     <select @change="onChange" class="form-control" v-model="selected">
         <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
         <option v-for='item,key in items' :value="item">@{{ item.name }}</option>
     </select>
```

```
       <hr/><div class="row" v-bind:style="{ 'display' : displayShow }" v-cloak>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Items Table</h3>
              <table class="table light-table-1">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> ID </th>
                  <th> Name </th>
                  <th> + Add </th>
                  <th> - Remove </th>
                  <th> Discription </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody v-for='newItem in newItems'>
                <tr>
                  <td v-text="newItem.id"> </td>
                  <td v-text="newItem.name"> </td>
                  <td> <input type="number" v-model="newItem.add" v-text="newItem.add"> </td>
                  <td> <input type="number" v-model="newItem.remove" v-text="newItem.remove"> </td>
                  <td> <textarea cols="45" rows="2" v-model="newItem.disc" v-text="newItem.disc"> 
                  </textarea> </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
          <button type="submit" class="btn green">Submit</button>
      </div>
   </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="newItem[]" v-model="newItems">

      </form>
```

this is the vue js part

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
      displayShow:'none',
      selected:'',
      items:[],
      newItems:[],
    },
    mounted(){
      axios.post('/getData')
      .then((response) => this.items=response.data)
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    },
    methods:{
      onChange(event){
        var newVal = this.selected;
        newVal.add = "";
        newVal.remove = "";
        newVal.disc = "";
        this.newItems.push(newVal);
        this.displayShow = '';
        console.log(this.newItems);
      }
    }

  })
```

this is when I dd()
    [image]

Comment: Can you post the code where you `dd()` the request ?

Comment: dd($request->all());

Comment: What about `dd($request->input('newItem'))`, what does this give you?

Comment: @Djip still same [object object], [object object]

Comment: I am not so sure but what about json_encode($request->input('newItem'))